# How to preg_replace pattern on string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

This is what I did till now:

```
<?php 
    $patterns= '/staff_(?)/';
    $replacements= '';
    $string = 'staff_name as user_name';
    $string2 = 'staff_phone as user_phone';
    echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string)."<br>";
    echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string2);
?>
```

Output expecting is :

> "staff_name as user_name" should return "name"
>
> "staff_phone as user_phone" should return "phone"

Comment: You need to learn about quantifiers, backreferences.  Please refer to a manual first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Regex way....

```
<?php
$str='staff_name as user_name';
echo $str = preg_replace("~staff_(.*?)_~","", $str); //"prints" name
$str='staff_name as user_phone';
echo $str = preg_replace("~staff_(.*?)_~","", $str); //"prints" phone
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/124127)

[image]

### Non- Regex way using PHP native functions..

```
<?php
$str='staff_name as user_name';
$name_arr = explode('_',$str);
echo $name = array_pop($name_arr); //"prints" name

$str='staff_name as user_phone';
$phone_arr = explode('_',$str);
echo $phone = array_pop($phone_arr); //"prints" phone
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/124136)

Answer (score 0):

Use this `.*_(\w+$)`

Do like this

```
 <?php

   $string = 'staff_name as user_name';
   $string2 = 'staff_phone as user_phone';
   echo preg_replace('/.*_(\w+$)/', '$1', $string)."\n";
   echo preg_replace('/.*_(\w+$)/', '$1', $string2);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://eval.in/124118)</kbd>